# Drywall installation when ceiling joists lower at the edge

Tags: drywall, ceiling, joists, crack, drywall-mud

I am trying to install ceiling drywall and everything is fine until I reach the edge.

You can see there are 3 2x8 joists at the edge and it's somehow positioned 1/2" to 1" lower than the rest. So my drywall basically flush to the bottom of the 2x8 lumbers.

My questions are:

1. Is it OK to just putting drywall compound and paper and sand this 6" area? I think it will terribly crack later due to wood vs. drywall movement.
2. If not, how best to cover this area and make it smooth with the rest of the ceiling without having to use any trim/moulding?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

Here is another photo at the corner where the joist lumber is almost 1/2" lower:

[image]

3. Could I use Floor Ram Board such as https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ram-Board-38-in-x-50-ft-Temporary-Floor-Protection-Roll-RB-38x50/202823781 to nail and create a smooth transition?
4. Could I use 1/4" plywood with 3 feet width and mount as in the green area below? Then I can slowly mud the 1/4" thickness difference to spread for maybe 1-2 feet more.
5. Would "Rock Hard Water Putty" (https://www.walmart.com/ip/Rock-Hard-1-Water-Putty-1-lb-Cream-Powder/23217846) work to fill the gap and not use anything else? I have tried this before and it's as hard as wood once dried.

[image]

Comment: I would build it out with some more lumber, then drywall it. Essentially you'd have a 4" or so drop and 6" out from the wall. It'll resemble a cabling or duct run. In fact, it appears as though doing something like this would match up perfectly with the protruding wall in the second picture.

Comment: "4" or so drop" is quite a lot. But I got the idea. Maybe 1-2" is OK

Comment: I'd make it drop enough to get a corner bead over the corner with at least an inch between the edge of the bead and the ceiling so that it'll look cleaner after mudding.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. That's in no way going to yield a satisfactory result for the reason you mentioned.
2. By now you realize that you should've examined the framing before you began hanging drywall. You have two options:

   - Pull down part of the drywall and install shims on the joists approaching the beam to blend into it, creating a downslope in the ceiling. You could reduce the amount of the slope by using some 1/4" drywall under the beam itself and setting your other drywall flush with that.
   - Pull down all the drywall and shim the entire area down flush with the beam.

Comment: Option 2(b) is not possible because that would redo my 2 weekends and I have to re-rent the drywall lift for a 15'x9' area. Plus it will make the hole ceiling 1/2" lower. Option 1(a) is potential but it still require to pull down 4x8 drywall piece to insert the shim, which is a 2-person job (if without lift). What if there is an option to mount some plastic, wood panel or even metal below the 3 joists but overlap with the drywall for 2-3 feet out? Then I can mud the gap of the overlap to slowly even out the surface... Just thinking

Comment: I have provided updates with more options

Answer (score 1):

I would cover the dropped area with pieces of drywall and then tape it and finish normally. Or - just fill the holes in the wood, paint it and move on. Here's another idea - put a piece of crown molding over it.

Comment: "cover the dropped area with pieces of drywall and then tape it and finish normally" <-- I am interested to know how to deal with the thickness gap. Please see my update

Comment: What would "normally" be in this case? How does crown molding, most of which is under 4" in depth, help here?

Comment: After seeing the updated pictures, I would cover it with drywall and then tape, and finish.

Comment: I think what he means by cover "normally" is put the drywall over the studs and not "blend" the two levels together or try to mate them but make it a corner. The lower level will line up with the post that's there so it shouldn't look bad. I think this was suggested by stevieb in the comments